# Can aggregate return new Date?

Tags: mongodb

The document is:

```
{
  time: ISODate("2016-12-05T14:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

Suppose that:

Today is "2016-12-06", i want to do some aggregation,it'll return

```
{
  time: ISODate("2016-12-06T14:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

Today is "2016-12-07",it'll return

```
{
  time: ISODate("2016-12-07T14:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

so,the result is the date of now + the time of field

i have consulted all of the [Aggregation Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and just found some Date Getters operators,not Date Setters

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for your question.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            "customDate":  { $add : new Date() }
        }
    }
])
```

The output of above query will look like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584d3fdf08e6815847d15fe7"),
    "customDate" : ISODate("2016-12-14T03:23:20.077Z")
}
```

Comment: so your expected output should be **ISODate("2016-12-14T00:00:00.000Z")** only

Comment: It should be ISODate("2016-12-14T14:00:00.000Z"),it is the date of now + the time of field